# Enhanced third-party access for Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-visualization, google-sheets-api

With the changes to third-party access protection for Google Sheets, calls to the Visualization API now require OAuth credentials unless Spreadsheets are shared to "anyone who has the link can view".  ([Google Developers Blog Post](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2016/08/enhanced-third-party-access-protection.html))([Google Charts Authorization](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets#authorization))

Does this still apply to Spreadsheets that are shared to "anyone at domain with the link can view"?  If so, how would I get a OAuth credential without prompting the end user for access to their Drive or Spreadsheets?  Is it possible to pass a credential using a service account?  We do not want to prompt every user that uses the application, since it has been authorized by a Google Apps Administrator and executes using service accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Does this still apply to Spreadsheets that are shared to "anyone at domain with the link can view"?

It is stated in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets#authorization) that:

> Google Sheets requires end-user credentials to access private
> spreadsheets via the Google Visualization API ("/tq requests")

but Take NOTE that:

> Spreadsheets shared to "anyone who has the link can view" do not
> require credentials. Changing your spreadsheet's sharing settings is
> much easier than implementing authorization.

So if your spreadsheets is shared to "anyone who has the link can view", you are not affected by this update beginning September 14, 2016.

For more information, check this [thread](http://indianexpress.com/article/technology/tech-news-technology/google-sheets-enhanced-third-party-access-protection-2970453/).

Answer (score 0):

The "Anyone at domain with the link can view" still requires OAuth credentials, since the application is accessing non-public data. If you are using domain-wide delegation and service account impersonation, you can simply generate an access token in your backend and pass it in the requests to the `/tq` endpoint.